# How to upgrade drush version 5.4 to 7 or 8 for drush8

Tags: drupal-8, drush

I am user `drush version 5.4` for `drupal 7`. its is working fine but I am unable to use `drush` this version with for `drupal 8`.

I need to upgrade `drush` version.
please provide any solution.

Comment: You want to search for "composer install drush" using the search engine of your choice. There you will find links like this: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ - the official drush documentation. Follow their instructions. Alternatively you can search SO for "drush and composer": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php+drush

Comment: http://www.innoraft.com/blog/how-install-latest-drush-7-version-so-you-can-use-drush-brand-new-drupal-8